# I want to change the background colour of columns of ant design table if the index of my data is even

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, ant-design-pro

I want to change the background colour of columns of ant design table if the index of my data is even any idea how to change the background of columns on this condition.i have data in list want to set a condition through loop any idea how to change the background of columns in ant design.

```
 const [dataSource, setDataSource] = useState([])
 const { list } = useSelector((state) => state.userData) 
  useEffect(() => {

    dispatch(getData(token))
    setDataSource(list)
    dispatch(getDataofFormularyDrug(0))

   }, [])

      <Table
    columns={columns}
    // dataSource={list}
    dataSource={dataSource}
    pagination={{
      pageSize: 10
    }}
  />
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do this using the CSS pseudo-class `:nth-child()` with the keyword `even` to change the background color for each table cell. In your CSS File you can add the following line bellow:

```css
.ant-table-tbody .ant-table-cell:nth-child(even) {
  background-color: #fafafa;
}
```

I created a complete example at CodePen with the basic table from Ant Design changing the background color for the table cell when it is even. Follow the link: https://codepen.io/marcelofreires/pen/eYyZqer.

Comment: I want to change the color of even index of an array not an even cell in the table any ways thanks for answering.

Comment: I guessed that you would want to change the background color of columns when the index was even. The visual result of the code above will be columns with an even index with `background-color: #fafafa` . Did you see the codepen link on the answer? Is it what you want to do?

Comment: yes I saw the code but I dont want to change in a specific column I want to change the background colour of cells  on the basis of even Index.

Comment: I have a table with 100 columns. every 5 columns is a one product. How can I change the color every 5 columns? to better visualize the products 5 by 5?